# Debugging a JavaScript Freecodecamp challenge

Tags: javascript

I have been stumped by this challenge and I really don't understand why my code won't work. The challenge is "Basic JavaScript: Record Collection" from Freecodecamp.

The challenge is:

> "If the value parameter isn’t an empty string, update (or set) the value parameter for the prop parameter. 
>   If the prop parameter is equal to "tracks" and the value isn’t an empty string, push the value onto the end of the tracks array.
>   If value is an empty string, delete that prop from the object.
>   Finally, return the collection object.

Code:

```
 var collection = {
    "2548": {
      "album": "Slippery When Wet",
      "artist": "Bon Jovi",
      "tracks": [ 
        "Let It Rock", 
        "You Give Love a Bad Name" 
      ]
    },
    "2468": {
      "album": "1999",
      "artist": "Prince",
      "tracks": [ 
        "1999", 
        "Little Red Corvette" 
      ]
    },
    "1245": {
      "artist": "Robert Palmer",
      "tracks": [ ]
    },
    "5439": {
      "album": "ABBA Gold"
    }
};
// Keep a copy of the collection for tests
var collectionCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));

// Only change code below this line
function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {

  if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {
    if (collection.id.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    collection[id][prop].push(value);
    }
  else {
    collection.id.prop = [value];
  }
}

  else if (value !== "") {
    collection.id.prop = value;
  }

  else {
    delete collection.id.prop;
  }

  return collection;
}

// Alter values below to test your code
updateRecords(2468, "tracks", "ABBA");
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete description of the problem with working code and expected input/output, please? What does `collection` look like?

Comment: I've now added the whole code and details about the question.

Comment: Have you try comparing value !== null || value  !==undefined, empty string '' is neither of those, and since you are applying a strict ==! operator comparison there is no value coercion

Comment: [FreeCodeCamp got it's own forum](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/) for questions like these. Have a look there and you might find some decent answers. (I remember answering this question in the forum a couple of times when I contributed there, I will try to post it here if I found it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I've added comments for clarity. Let me know if you don't understand something.

```
 var collection = {
  "2548": {
    "album": "Slippery When Wet",
    "artist": "Bon Jovi",
    "tracks": [ 
      "Let It Rock", 
      "You Give Love a Bad Name" 
    ]
  },
  "2468": {
    "album": "1999",
    "artist": "Prince",
    "tracks": [ 
      "1999", 
      "Little Red Corvette" 
    ]
  },
  "1245": {
    "artist": "Robert Palmer",
    "tracks": [ ]
  },
  "5439": {
    "album": "ABBA Gold"
  }
};

function updateRecords(id, prop, value) {
  // Exit function if required items are missing
  if (!id || !collection) return;

  // We can't assume that collection will have [id]
  if (!collection.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
    collection[id] = [];
  }

  // Create an object reference to the id in the collection
  const reference = collection[id];

  // Now it's pretty straight forward after
  if (prop === "tracks" && value && typeof value === "string") {
    if (reference.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      reference[prop].push(value);
    } else {
      reference[prop] = [value];
    }
  } else if (value) {
    reference[prop] = value;
  } else {
    delete reference[prop];
  }

  return collection;
}

// Alter values below to test your code
updateRecords(2468, "tracks", "ABBA");
updateRecords(2468, "tracks", ["BETA"]);
updateRecords(2468, "tracks", "");
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking your time! Your answer is out of my understanding, but maybe that is because i did not add enough details in my question. If you got time, please take a look on my question again. I believe i am very close to it being correct, but it might be some syntax error or something.

Comment: @RajTeynar I've updated my example. You can run it and see that it works. Your biggest problem is that you're trying to access collection.id.porps. The name of the key is not 'id', you need to use bracket notation to replace id with the variable id passed into the function.

Comment: You're a champ. I changed the dots to brackets and it solved the problem. Thank you very much!